# Temporarily disable enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which alert user if he enters less than or more than chars.. in the line of textarea.

In addition to that I'd like to disable "Enter button" `e.which == 13` if condition is not meeting requirements.

I wonder how I can disable/enable enter button `e.which == 13` if some of requirements are not met. Thanks

```
$('#customnumbers').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i] != '\n' && (lines[i].length < 7 || lines[i].length > 15)) {
                alert('Number must be more than 7 and less than 15 characters.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can stop the key event from bubbling up by calling `e.preventDefault()`. This will not "disable" the enter key on your browser (which cannot be done), but it will make sure that whatever else would happen after pressing enter on that field does not get executed..

Comment: Do you really want to disable the enter button? Or do you just want to prevent form submission?

Comment: I want to disable enter button when there are more than 15 and less than 7 characters. When users enter from 7 to 15 characters I want to enable enter button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this code, by showing a div message instead of an alert :

```
$('#customnumbers').keypress(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode === 10 || e.keyCode === 13) 


        var text = $(this).val();
        var lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i] != '\n' && (lines[i].length < 7 || lines[i].length > 15)) {
                var myMessageDiv=$('<div class="myMessageDiv">Number must be more than 7 and less than 15 characters.</div>');
                myMessageDiv.insertBefore( "#customnumbers" );

                setTimeout(function(){ $('.myMessageDiv').remove(); }, 3000);  // after 3 seconds remove message.

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the enter key this way:

```
$('body').bind('keypress', function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
    return false;
    }
 });
```

Hope it helps.